# when I use If isset($_FILES['something'] I can't access my controller array in my view in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

when I load same view in If Else condition I cant access my view as data in view control !! For Example (This code is for Edit Profile pic)

```
if(isset($_FILES['file1']))
{ 
    //here some code to upload photo and resize it
    $data2['avtar'] = $this->upload_model->update_photo($source) //Retriving data from model 
    $this->load->view('profile_view',$data2,TRUE);
}
else
{
    $this->load->view('profile_view');
}
```

I can't access `$data2['avtar']` value in my view !! when I remove third parameter true I can see its value in view using `var_dump($avtar)` but it loads two view of same page and mixed in one another. I want to access only image path to view whom I can put in `<img src="">` in my view. so tell me whats the problem?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Docs](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html)

> If you set the parameter to true (boolean) it will return data. The
>   default behavior is false, which sends it to your browser. Remember to
>   assign it to a variable if you want the data returned:

```
$string = $this->load->view('myfile', '', true);
```

By examining the provided code, I can not see how it loads two view of same page. Maybe your code is in a loop.

You can also use AJAX to update the image.